# Transforming coordinates in python

Tags: python, coordinates

I have one coordinate system 4.3, 50.8, 4.4, 50.9 and I want to convert points in that box to a box that is 4800X4800 pixels. Is there anything in the python language that can help do these conversions or do I have to write the math myself?

Comment: First off: what does your original coordinate system: `4.3, 50.8, 4.4, 50.9` mean? Are those `x` vs `y` dimensions? What are they?

Comment: They were lat and lon coordinates that have already been flattened

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I have understood what you require, then I would recommend numpy for this: http://www.numpy.org/

Here are the methods I would use:

```
y = numpy.linspace(50.8,50.9,4800)
x = numpy.linspace(4.3,4.4,4800)
x,y = numpy.meshgrid(x,y)
```

linspace will generate, in this instance, 4800 values linearly interpolated between 50.8 and 50.9 for y and 4.3 and 4.4 for x.  meshgrid is then employed to form these 1D coordinate arrays into two 2D coordinate arrays (both of size 4800 by 4800 pixels) for both the x and y values.

Answer (score 0):

You could write something like this:

```
def remap_coords(x, y, x_min=4.3, y_min=50.8,
                 x_max=4.4, y_max=50.9, width=4800, height=4800):
    new_x = (x - x_min) / (x_max - x_min) * width
    new_y = (y - y_min) / (y_max - y_min) * height
    return (int(round(new_x)), int(round(new_y)))
```